# How to put an attribute to Canvas element for Flutter Web?

Tags: javascript, html, flutter, canvas, attributes

I am rendering Flutter Web as a canvas. Element's HTML code is like this;

```
<flt-scene-host aria-hidden="true" style="pointer-events: none;">
 <flt-scene>
  <flt-canvas-container>
   <canvas width="2580" height="1900" style="position: absolute; width: 1290px; height: 950px; transform: translate(0px, 0px);">
   </canvas>
  </flt-canvas-container>
  </flt-scene>
</flt-scene-host>
```

I want to add this property to the canvas object. Canvas is created dynamically, it does not exist in index.html. I tried adding with JS but the selector didn't work well and page loading is kinda unstable since it is SPA.

`data-sl-experimental="canvas-mq"`

The expected result HTML is:

```
<flt-scene-host aria-hidden="true" style="pointer-events: none;">
 <flt-scene>
  <flt-canvas-container>
   <canvas data-sl-experimental="canvas-mq" width="2580" height="1900" style="position: absolute; width: 1290px; height: 950px; transform: translate(0px, 0px);">
   </canvas>
  </flt-canvas-container>
 </flt-scene>
</flt-scene-host>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Canvas is generated on runtime, you have two options

1. modify `web/index.html` file and add attribute `data-sl="canvas-mq"` to `<body> element` as this particular attribute is inherited.
2. edit the flutter engine initialization in `web/index.html` like this

   ```
    window.addEventListener("load", function (ev) {
        // Download main.dart.js
        _flutter.loader
            .loadEntrypoint({
                serviceWorker: {
                    serviceWorkerVersion: serviceWorkerVersion,
                },
            })
            .then(function (engineInitializer) {
                return engineInitializer.initializeEngine();
            })
            .then(function (appRunner) {
                return appRunner.runApp();
            })
            .then(function (app) {
                window.setTimeout(function () {
                    const canvasElement = document
                        .querySelector("flt-glass-pane")
                        .shadowRoot.querySelector("canvas");
                    canvasElement.dataset.slExperimental = "canvas-mq"
                }, 200);
           });
       });
   ```

I would recommend modifying index.html (1. option) as it should be more straightforward.